# Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, with index $p$ prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I proved that each subgroup is of the form $\{(s,t):as+bt\equiv0\mod p\}$. Then, how can I show that the number of such subgroups is $p+1$?

Comment: @DerekHolt You should give that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

All such subgroups contain $p{\mathbb Z} \times p{\mathbb Z}$, so the problem is equivalent to finding the subgroups of order $p$ in $({\mathbb Z} \times {\mathbb Z})/(p{\mathbb Z} \times p{\mathbb Z}) \cong {\mathbb Z}_p \times {\mathbb Z}_p$. Each such subgroup contains $p−1$ nonidentity elements, and any two such subgroups intersect in the identity only, so there are $(p^2-1)/(p-1)=p+1$ subgroups.